How to use git commands via sshagent in Jenkins?
Good afternoon, I ran into the problem that I can't use git commands via sshagent.
The idea is that I upload an update to GitHub, a hook is triggered, jenkins connects to a remote node, stops the container, receives an update from GitHub, and then starts the container again.
I was able to write a Pipeline that starts and stops the container.
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('SSH') {
            steps {
                sshagent(credentials: ['docker-work']) {
                    sh "ssh -tt -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@192.168.0.103 docker-compose -f /home/CloudToDoList/CloudToDoList/docker-compose.yml stop"
                    sh "ssh -tt -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@192.168.0.103 docker-compose -f /home/CloudToDoList/CloudToDoList/docker-compose.yml up -d"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

but there were problems with the git commands
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('SSH') {
            steps {
                sshagent(credentials: ['docker-work']) {
                    sh "ssh -tt -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@192.168.0.103 git --git-dir=/home/CloudToDoList/CloudToDoList/.git log"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

If I use such a Pipeline, it goes into an endless download.
But the command itself is working, regardless of the repository, everything is output correctly (I use log just for testing)
root@docker-work:~# git --git-dir=/home/CloudToDoList/CloudToDoList/.git log
commit 660e12c50978995333eebeeecdcf2a71d6747961 (HEAD -> master, origin/master)
Author: root <root@docker-work.samovar.ru>
Date:   Thu Oct 24 14:27:28 2024 +0000

    готовая страница Note, File, Task, GroupTask, TaskForGroup

